# updating a URLs, functions: Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this `next()` function that's suppose to cycle through an array of 9 images. The variable `path` should hold the image `id`s from the URL.

An example URL is `http://localhost:4200/image/1;id=1;category=testing` and `path` stores the id after /image/**'1'**`.

The parameters after the image `id` is an array called `domain` that I use to keep track of which domain the user is in. It's always constant unless the users switches domain.

My issue is whenever I use the `next()` function based on tracking the `this.activeId` with the `console.log` the `activeId` before I hit it would be 1 and then after it would be 2. However if I hit the `next()` function again the `Before: 1 After: 2` remains the same. The `id` does not update and the URL does not change. Instead it remains:  `http://localhost:4200/image/1;id=1;category=testing`.

If possible can somebody help me to fix this issue.

```js
  ngOnInit() {

        this.route.params.subscribe(response => {
          let path = window.location.pathname.split(";")[0].split("/").pop();
          this.activeId = parseInt(path);
          console.log("ActiveId",this.activeId);
          this.testing =  this.graphService.getTestingGraphs(parseInt(path));
          this.utilities =  this.graphService.getUtilitiesGraphs(parseInt(path));
          this.image = this.imageService.getImage(parseInt(path));
        });

}

  next() {
    console.log("Before", this.activeId);
    const next = parseInt(this.activeId) + 1 >= 9 ? 1: parseInt(this.activeId) + 1;
    console.log("After", next);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/image/' + `${next};id=${this.domain.id};category=${this.domain.category}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `this.route.params.subscribe(...)` running multiple times?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I was more thinking it's only running once. How would I be able to tell?

Comment: Are you seeing this logged each time you click your next button which should trigger a route change? `console.log("ActiveId",this.activeId);`

Comment: Oh I see now, It only gets it once from the ngOnit. It should be updated when I click the next() as well. Is that even possible to fix?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel